# How to show a popup graph/chart from jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using **free-jqgrid/4.13.3**. Onclick of a **cell** it should **popup a window** to display a **line chart**. I am using **jqplot** (jquery.jqplot.js, jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js, jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js) for chart. Expecting dialog window will contain the chart. 
I am unable to achieve this using the below code:

```
{ name: 'show_chart', index: 'show_chart', align: 'center', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: false,
    formatter:"showlink",
    formatoptions: {
        onClick: function (options) {
        $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $("#dialog").dialog({
         open: function() {
                var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,5,3,8,2,5]]);
               }  
        });
        return false;
       }
    }}
```

In html body:

```
<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" hidden="true">
</body>
```

Any kind of help on this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should divide the problem in parts: 1) usage of `formatter:"showlink"` 2) usage of jQuery UI dialog 3) the usage of `$.jqplot`. I can help you only with the first 2 parts because I don't use `$.jqplot`. Independent on your question I'd recommend you don't use old 4.13.3 version and upgrade to the current 4.15.2 version of free jqGrid, which I published yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what the problem is without the full source of the html and javascript. I have made some assumptions and put together a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea04896p/) that illustrates what you are trying to achieve.

The main changes I see are...

1. In onclick you never actually call open on the dialog. For example,
   `$("#dialog").dialog("open");`
2. There needs to be html elements for the grid and chart